# $\,m = {\rm lcm}(a,b)\iff a,b\mid m\ \, \& \ \gcd(m/a,m/b)=1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, arithmetic

For $a \in\Bbb  N$, $b\in\Bbb  N$, $μ \in\Bbb N^*$,
we have $μ = \operatorname{lcm}(a,b) \iff  μ = αa\text{ and }μ= βb$ and $\gcd(α,β)$ is $1$

Till now I succeeded to prove the left $\Rightarrow$ right implication, now I need to prove the reciprocal ($\Leftarrow$ way)

Here is my work:
[image: http://imgur.com/a/oPy6XDN]

Can someone help me, or give me a hint? Rules : you can't use the expression ($a \wedge b)(a\vee b)=ab$, $(ka)\vee(vkb) = k(a\vee b)$ 
+ You can also help me improve my redaction if possible..

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: It doesn't solve my problem. Most of the solutions there use the expression (a∧b)(a∨b)=ab that I'm not allowed to use...

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  For equations, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Shouldn't that be $\mu = a \vee b$?

Comment: Did my alternative proof not work for you?

Comment: I didn't use your proof since it's not what I was looking for, however, I found exactly what I needed on reddit : https://www.reddit.com/r/cheatatmathhomework/comments/bsagvz/lcm_theorem_proof/

Answer (score 1):

[This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2127538/242) proves the theorem below using  basic divisibility laws (by exploiting innate $\rm\color{#c00}{duality}$).

**Theorem** $\  $ If $\,\ a,b\mid m\,\ $ then  $\ \displaystyle \frac{m}{{\rm lcm}(a,b)} \,=\,\gcd\left(\frac{m}a,\frac{m}b\right),\ $ i.e. $\ \color{#c00}{{\rm lcm}(a,b)' = \gcd(a',b')}$

$\begin{align}{\rm We\ seek}\ \   m = {\rm lcm}(a,b) &\iff a,b\mid m\ \ \&\  \gcd\left(\dfrac{m}a,\dfrac{m}b\right) = 1,\ \ \text{which by the above is}\\[.3em]
 &\iff a,b\mid m\ \ \&\ \ \dfrac{m}{{\rm lcm}(a,b)}\, =\, 1,\quad\ \ \ \text{which is clearly true.}
\end{align}$

**Remark** $ $ The linked proof using cofactor duality reveals your equivalence boils down to

${\rm lcm}(a,b) = m \iff {\rm lcm}(a,b)' = m',\ $ via $\ {\rm lcm}(a,b)' = \gcd(a',b') = \gcd(m/a,m/b)$

---

**Alternatively** $ $ we show: $ $ a common multiple $m$ of $\,a,b\,$ is *least* $\iff \gcd(m/a,m/b)=1$

**Proof** $\ $ If the gcd $= c> 1\,$ then $\,c\mid m/a,m/b\,$ so $\,a,b\mid m/c,\,$ therefore  $m$ is not least. $ $ Conversely, if $m$ is not least [then](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2038083/242) $\,m = c\ell\,$ for $\,\ell\,$ least, so the gcd $= (c\ell/a,c\ell/b) = c(\ell/a,\ell/b) > 1\,$ by $\,c>1$.

Comment: The problem is that my teacher won't accept this as a proof since he told us to prove it only by using divisibility laws and gcf laws, and I'm not allowed to use that expression even if it's derived as a corollary... + One more thing I'm not allowed to use fractions : notice how I didn't use any in my paper. I hope you understand, thanks.

Comment: @Mrkinix Again, the linked proof uses only simple divisibility laws and the definition of gcd and lcm. You can ignore the Corollary since I don't use it above.

Comment: @Mrkinix I added an alternative proof.